# Is there formula for calculating how much continuous current and max current a motor driver can supply given a certain temperature?

Tags: current, dc-motor, heat, thermal, motordriver

Note I am a beginner :)

https://www.monolithicpower.com/pub/media/cms_document/category_documents/AN124_r1.0.pdf This 'paper' shows how the heat of a motor driver reduces the current that can be supplied to the motor for different packages on a PCB board.

Is there formula for calculating how much continuous current, and max current a motor driver can supply given a certain temperature?

If not, what would be the method to test continuous current and max current given a temperature?

Comment: Actually if someone devolops a drive, it's wise to hire a company that specializes on such analysis. You give them the list of components, power and environment conditions, they run a simulation and provide you with temperature and safety margins on each component. It a full scale project.

Comment: However with some experience you can make assumptions and create margins to be on the safe side while not spending time and money on this research. You cut corners and take some risk, but save some twenty grand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a simple plug & chug *formula*, but there is a well-defined *method*.  It's based on the simple rule that power electronics tend to burn up, and that's not a desirable thing.

So you do the following:

1. For each sensitive part in the circuit, determine its power dissipation.  Power dissipation comes from the voltage drop multiplied by the current.  (Note that for switching drives this is not trivial, and sometimes requires you to use a circuit simulator to estimate it up front, and measurements to estimate it after the fact).
2. For each sensitive part in the circuit, determine its temperature rise per unit power (AKA thermal resistance -- usually degrees C per watt).
3. From these, determine the temperature rise from ambient.
4. From these temperatures, determine if things will burn up.
5. If you have the opportunity, circle back and decrease the power dissipation or the thermal resistance until you know things will work.

The sensitive parts are usually the power semiconductors (IC's and transistors), resistors, inductors, and circuit board traces.

This is *really simplified* -- in particular, the first few steps can take some serious work.  But it's the method that usually works (and when it goes wrong it's often in fixable ways).

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your answer! In essence are you saying that the current of my motor driver should be low enough that heat generated doesn't destroy components on my circuit.